# how to move region to other window?

Tags: window, text-editing, kill-ring

How can I automatically move selected to the other window? Trying to streamline my split-window workflow.

Here's what I have so far. Doesn't work yet.

```
(defun move-region-to-other-window (start end)
  "Move selected text to other window"
  (interactive "r")
  (if (use-region-p) 
      (let ((count (count-words-region start end)))
        (save-excursion
          (kill-region start end)
          (other-window)          
          (yank)
          (newline))
        (other-window)         
        (message "Moved %s words" count))
    (message "No region selected")))
```

Attribution: Code above is based on danielsz's excellent package [Palimpsest Mode](https://github.com/danielsz/Palimpsest).

Comment: I suppose people can just copy and evaluate your code and try it out to see what "doesn't work yet" means, but it would be nice nevertheless if you could provide this info right away.

Comment: Seems like `append-to-buffer` does what you want, except for killing the region afterward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is alright except that it is missing the mandatory arguments to the [`other-window`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/other-window) command.

From the function documentation (<kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> `other-window` <kbd>RET</kbd>),

> ```
> (other-window COUNT &optional ALL-FRAMES)
> ```
>
> Select another window in cyclic ordering of windows.
> COUNT specifies the number of windows to skip, starting with the
> selected window, before making the selection. If COUNT is
> positive, skip COUNT windows forwards. If COUNT is negative,
> skip -COUNT windows backwards. COUNT zero means do not skip any
> window, so select the selected window. In an interactive call,
> COUNT is the numeric prefix argument. Return nil.

#### Fixed code

```
(defun move-region-to-other-window (start end)
  "Move selected text to other window"
  (interactive "r")
  (if (use-region-p) 
      (let ((count (count-words-region start end)))
        (save-excursion
          (kill-region start end)
          (other-window 1)   
          (yank)
          (newline))
        (other-window -1)     
        (message "Moved %s words" count))
    (message "No region selected")))
```

Comment: @PeterSalazar: This is the core problem: the function works if you change `(other-window)` to `(other-window 1)`.  However, it will insert the text wherever point happens to be: maybe consider adding something like `(goto-char (point-max))` right before the `(yank)` if you want it added to the *end* of the buffer.

Comment: @Dan: I guess what the OP might actually *want* could be adding text at point.

Comment: Yes, adding text at point is in fact the desired behavior, allows more precision.